# Errors occuring when using accelerometer in android

Tags: android, multithreading, accelerometer

I am getting some errors when using the accelerometer sensor.
These errors don't affect the functioning of the class, but when I press the back button , my application is "force closed."

```
09-22 21:33:17.119: E/SensorManager(1397): registerListener :: handle = 0  
  name=  BMA220 delay= 20000 Listener= com.ic.edata.GameActivity@4053b4e8

09-22 21:33:17.119: E/SensorManager(1397): =======>>>Sensor Thread RUNNING <<<========
09-22 21:33:17.129: E/SensorManager(1397): reg :: handle = 0

09-22 21:33:17.139: E/SensorManager(1397): registerListener :: handle = 0 
 name= BMA220       delay= 20000 Listener= com.ic.edata.GameActivity@4053b4e8

09-22 21:33:17.149: E/SensorManager(1397): reg :: handle = 0

09-22 21:33:36.029: E/SensorManager(1397): unregisterListener:: handle = 0 
Listener=  com.ic.edata.GameActivity@4053b4e8 name = BMA220

09-22 21:33:36.029: E/SensorManager(1397): unregisterListener:: handle = 0
 Listener= com.ic.edata.GameActivity@4053b4e8 name = BMA220

09-22 21:33:36.179: E/SensorManager(1397): unregisterListener:: handle = 0 
Listener= com.ic.edata.GameActivity@4053b4e8 name = BMA220
```

`

My code for this activity is

```
package com.ic.edata;

import java.util.Random;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

float x,y,sensorX,sensorY,a,b;
Bitmap ball,end1;
SensorManager sm;
MySurfaceView ourSurfaceView;
Thread ourThread = null;
int count=0;
Sensor s;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0)
    {
        s = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    } 
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blueball2);
    end1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.end1);
    x=y=sensorX=sensorY=0;
    a=150;
    b=170;
    ourSurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() //main thread stopped
{
    sm.unregisterListener(this,s);
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    sm.unregisterListener(this, s);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {     
    sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sensorX=-event.values[0];
    sensorY=event.values[1];

    x=x+sensorX;
    y=y+sensorY;


}



public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();

    }

    public void pause()
    {
        isRunning=false;
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread=null;
    }


    public void resume() 
    {
        isRunning=true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(isRunning)
        {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;
            Random r = new Random();
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(230, 223, 223));
            Paint p1 = new Paint(Color.BLACK);
            p1.setTextSize(25);
            float endx=a;
            float endy=b;
            if(x>canvas.getWidth())
                x=0-ball.getWidth();
            if(y>canvas.getHeight())
                y=0-ball.getHeight();
            if(x<0-ball.getWidth())
                x=canvas.getWidth();
            if(y<0-ball.getHeight())
                y=canvas.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(end1, endx, endy, null);
            if((x>endx-16)&&(x<endx+24)&&(y>endy)&&(y<endy+24))
            {
                a=r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-40);
                b=r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-40);
                x=r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
                y=r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
                count++;
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, null);
            canvas.drawText("Score : "+count, 
canvas.getWidth()/2-45,    20, p1);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onDestroy();
    super.onBackPressed();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

put unregistering in a try catch block, its unregistering in onPause and then getting exception in ondestroy because theres nothing to unregister

Comment: thnx...it worked for some errors but I am still getting the first three errors in LogCat

Comment: well using a try catch the exeption will still show up, is it still crashing?

Comment: It stops randomly...like after it has been called 5 or 6 times

Comment: the sensor thread running error occurs only when activity is called first time along with other two errors . afterwards only other two error occurs

Answer (score 0):

First stop calling ondestroy() in onbackpress. ondestroy calls when it has to be call ucant forcfully call it

second for ur error... remove the code "sm.unregisterListener(this,s);"from destroy